# Your application is using the 'HealthKitUI' framework

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios9.3

I recently updated Xamarin. Ever since that time, I have been unable to build my iOS application due to this error:

> Your application is using the 'HealthKitUI' framework, which isn't
>       included in the iOS SDK you're using to build your app (this framework
>       was introduced in iOS 9.3, while you're building with the iOS 9.2
>       SDK.) This configuration is only supported with the legacy registrar
>       (pass --registrar:legacy as an additional mtouch argument in your
>       project's iOS Build option to select). Alternatively select a newer
>       SDK in your app's iOS Build options.

Has anyone else seen this? I haven't changed anything in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to upgrade to Xcode 7.3. Could you perform that update and let us know?

iOS 9.3 requires Xcode 7.3 support, these were added in Xamarin.iOS 9.6.0.0: https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-ios-9-3-xcode-7-3-support/

Also, [check out the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_SDK#iOS_9.x:_SDK) for information on iOS SDK releases against Xcode releases.